# Writing value to a column only once on list item creation

Tags: 2010, list, infopath, date-field

Using just SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath (with no access to SharePoint Designer or workflows) can the following be achieved?

**List Schema (Simplified):**

1. Action - Text Field
2. Current Target Date - Date Field
3. Original Target Date - Date Field

**Requirement:**

1. Use an InfoPath form for entry, only presenting the user with "Action" and "Current Target Date" to populate.
2. On record creation the value in "Current Target Date" is also written to "Original Target Date"
3. Any further updates to "Current Target Date" would not change "Original Target Date".

Thanks in advance for any help/advise provided.

Comment: You can customize the list form using infopath. Create 3 forms for new, display and edit. On new form set default value of Original Target Date to Current Target Date. On Edit form, don't change anything. See [this](https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/individual-newedit-and-display-forms-for-sharepoint-using-infopath-forms/) article on how create forms for list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of which version of InfoPath you're using (or if you can use 2013 in 2010 SP)... But with InfoPath 2013 at least, you can create rules on fields. In this case you'd want to set the following:

1. Create `dateCurrent` and `dateOriginal` Date Fields.
2. Go to `Manage Rules`, select `dateCurrent` and create a new `Action Rule`.
3. Add Rule:

   1. The Condition for the rule should be `if dateOriginal is Blank`
   2. The action should be of type `Set a field's value`
   3. Select `dateOriginal`
   4. in the `fx` popup by the `Value` field,
   5. select `insert Field or Group` and select `dateCurrent`.
4. Click OK on all the popups

The field should now update only if it's *empty* otherwise it'll copy whatever is in the CurrentDate field.

I assume there's a similar concept in InfoPath 2010, however I've never used it to confirm.

[image]

Comment: I think that may work quite well, will give it a go tomorrow. Thanks!